# If series $\sum4^nC_n$ is convergent, is $\sum(-2)^nC_n$ convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

We only know $\sum_{i=0}^n 4^nC_n$ is convergent, is the following series convergent?

$$\sum_{i=0}^n (-2)^nC_n$$

PS: I am trying to prove it is convergent in this way:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n (-2)^nC_n = \sum_{i=0}^n 4^n\Big(\frac{-1}{2}\Big)^nC_n$$

Using Ratio Test:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\left\lvert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} \right\rvert = 
\lim_{x \to \infty}\left\lvert \frac{4^{n+1}(1/2)^{n+1}C_{n+1}}{4^{n}(1/2)^{n}C_{n}} \right\rvert =\frac{1}{2} \lim_{x \to \infty}\left\lvert \frac{4^{n+1}C_{n+1}}{4^{n}C_{n}} \right\rvert$$

I just need to prove that above is smaller than 1. However, I **can not** conclude that if $\sum_{i=0}^n 4^nC_n$ is convergent, then

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\left\lvert \frac{4^{n+1}C_{n+1}}{4^{n}C_{n}} \right\rvert<1$$

Above is true only if $\sum_{i=0}^n 4^nC_n$ is absolute convergent.

Answer (score 3):

If your series converges it's necessary that $4^nC_n$ tends to zero so especially there is an $N$ s.t. for $n \ge N$ it holds $|4^nC_n| \le 1$.

But then
$$\left|(-2)^nC_n\right| = \left|4^n\Big(\frac{-1}{2}\Big)^nC_n\right| \le \frac{1}{2^n}$$

and so your new series converges absolutely.